# Array as Generic Type in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, generics, kotlin

I am getting an error asking for member declaration and I have no idea why. I have been trying to look things up but can't seem to find an answer to why this is invalid. I can do `val listOfArr = ArrayList<Array<String>>()` just fine. Why does this not work?

```
class Implements: IPatternCheck {

    override fun <Array<String>> check(classData: ClassData, value: Array<String>): Boolean {
       return true
    }
}
```

This is my interface

```
interface IPatternCheck {
    fun<T> check(classData: ClassData, value: T): Boolean
}
```

Comment: What does your interface look like? Which part of the code exactly do you want to make generic?

Comment: The check method I want to make it take a Array<String> type, but it's throwing me a compile error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your interface declares a function with a type parameter, you have to keep that type parameter intact when you override it - so you'd have to create this override for it in your class:

```
override fun <T> check(classData: ClassData, value: T): Boolean {
    // TODO
}
```

To make it take a specific type, you should make your interface generic instead of just the function inside it, and implement the interface with the specific type passed as the type parameter:

```
interface IPatternCheck<T>  {
    fun check(classData: ClassData, value: T): Boolean
}

class Implements: IPatternCheck<Array<String>> {
    override fun check(classData: ClassData, value: Array<String>): Boolean {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

---

Edit, answering the question in the comment below. If you do this:

```
override fun <String> check(classData: ClassData, value: String): Boolean {
    // TODO
}
```

... all you're doing is just *renaming* the `T` type parameter to `String` (rather confusingly). You're not actually using the `kotlin.String` class that stores a sequence of characters.

For example, you can still call an instance of `Implements` with any second parameter, it won't be restricted to a `kotlin.String`. It's still a generic function.

```
val implements = Implements()
implements.check(ClassData(), "foo")
implements.check(ClassData(), 25)
```

Also, you can't access any `kotlin.String` functions on the parameter:

```
override fun <String> check(classData: ClassData, value: String): Boolean {
    value.length // Unresolved reference: length
}
```

Comment: If I have to keep the type parameter for a generic function why can I do

   override fun <String> check(classData: ClassData, value: String): 
   Boolean {
      //TODO
   }